# Can I unshorten URLs sent to me before visiting them?

Tags: url-shortening

I often get sent URLs on Twitter when I have Tweets that are retweeted a lot. 
Naturally, I suspect Malware behind them, but is there any way to actually check the URL before you visit the page? By checking I mean either unshorten them and see the real link or to have a peek at that website without visiting it and endangering the safety of my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The individual shortening services all include a way of discovering the full URL behind (and sometimes what metrics are tracked), but there's also some web apps out there like [unshorten.me](http://unshorten.me/) that'll do it for you (possibly your best bet, it covers [t.co](http://t.co/), [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/), [bit.do](http://bit.do/), [tinurl](http://tinyurl.com/), [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/), [fb.me](http://fb.me/), [tr.im](http://tr.im/) and [ow.ly](http://ow.ly/))

Comment: I can't see an option for that on goo.gl. Which is mostly used by those people on Twitter. Maybe thats why :P.

Comment: What do you mean... you have a `goo.gl` URL and `unshorten.me` isn't expanding it?  The service claims it can do it.  Just add a `+` to the end of `goo.gl` URL to show where it's going to take you.

Comment: Google also runs their own service to unshorten goo.gl shortent urls.

Comment: @Rudu Nope, it does not want to unshorten this URL. The Web of Trust addon could though. Anyway, I am gonna accept it since unshorten.me was successful on other URLs such as bit.ly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [linkunshorten.com](https://linkunshorten.com/) which also offers a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-unshorten/fpdpbfkdodkadhickmncmaaklaafpplm) that handles automatically checking of short links. LinkUnshorten also shows you a screenshot of the site before you visit it.